# executing __constructor() in php inheritance

Tags: php, oop

In php, if A extends B, does B's _constrctor() get executed automatically when A is instantiated? or do I have to call parent->_constructor()?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP looks for the top-most (closest to the instantiated class) `__construct` method it can find.  It then executes that one only.

```
Class A {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "From A";
    }
}
Class B extends A {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "From B";
    }
}
Class C extends A {}
Class D extends B {}
Class E extends B {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "from E";
    }
}

new A(); // From A
new B(); // From B
new C(); // From A
new D(); // From B
new E(); // From E
```

And `parent` accesses the next one up the list until there are no more (at which point it'll generate an error)...

So, in class `E`, running `parent::__construct()` would execute class `B`'s constructor.

In class `B`, running `parent::__construct()` would execute class `A`'s constructor.

In class `A`, running `parent::__construct()` will generate an error since there is no constructor...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you have to call it.

A simple test:

```
class A {
      public function __construct() {
           echo 'A';
      }
}

class B extends A {
      public function __construct() {
           echo 'B';
      }
}

$ab = new B();
```

Should tell you all you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call "parent::__construct()" from A's constructor, if A has one. Otherwise you don't need to.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A {
    function __construct() {
        echo 5;
    }
}
class B_no_Constructor extends A {

}
class B_with_Constructor extends A {
    function __construct(){}
}
//try one
//new B_no_Constructor; //outputs 5
//new B_with_Constructor; //outputs nothing
```